# Tag rename request: azure-search → azure-cognitive-search

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

**Azure Search** is rebranding the service to **Azure Cognitive Search** on 11/4/2019. As part of this update, we'd like to have the Stack Overflow tag for the service match the new name.

This is a request for moderators to rename the tag [azure-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-search) to ***azure-cognitive-search***.  This change should apply to all existing questions with the current tag, with almost 1000 questions at this time.

Please retain the ***azure-search*** tag as a synonym of ***azure-cognitive-search***.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what the merit is of throwing in a useless adjective like "cognitive". It just makes the name harder to type and harder to remember. Everyone knows that search is a cognitive process. Anyway, how does this interact with the existing tags [[tag:azure-cognitive-services]] and [[tag:microsoft-cognitive]]? Do you want to wait and have this change go live closer to Nov 4, or does it make sense to do the tag rename now?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting downvotes.  Renaming the product to add 'cognitive' might be management/marketing sillyness; but the tag here should match the actual product name even if it is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Agreed, @Dan. It is a properly formed tag rename request, and it is almost certainly not Mike's decision to rename the product. That said, before I can implement this, I would still like to get the answers to the questions in my comment above.

Comment: Responses to the questions raised above: 1) As Dan suggested, we'd like the tag to  match the new product name.  Our broader goal is to make sure people can find questions related to the product when searched for both names, old or new. 2) This doesn't interact or overlap with the existing cognitive tags at Microsoft.  The cognitive services are a partner team of ours, but aren't impacted by this change.  3) This change can go live at any time, ideally by 11/4 since that's when we'll start announcing it.  As long as a synonym tag for the old name exists, I'd expect it would not be as noticed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make it easier for you to link to the new tag right away should you desire when preparing your announcement, I've renamed the tag to [azure-cognitive-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-cognitive-search) ahead of time, complete with making the old name a synonym of the new.

Comment: Thanks!  Did some testing and looks great.